# Выдача роли автору сообщения по реакции discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Задача у бота следующая: Администратор ставит реакцию на сообщение человека и тогда автору этого сообщения выдаются роли. Если какой то левый человек поставит реакцию, то ничего не произойдет. Я думаю, что когда человек пишет сообщение +регистрация (хочет зарегаться), то id сообщения попадает в словарь (ключ - пользователь, значение - id сообщения). И когда админ ставит реакцию, то бот ищет в словаре по значениям id сообщения, на которое поставлена реакция и ключу (пользователю) выдает роли. Но это как то слишком сложно. Есть ли еще варианты?

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True, kick_members=True) #проверяем наличие прав на управление ролями, банами и киками
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload): #отлов реакции на сообщение
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id) #отлов канала, где произошла реакция
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) #отлов сообщения из канала, где произошла реакция
    user = message.user #получаем автора сообщения
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Test") #находим роль по имени на сервере
    await bot.add_roles(user, role) #выдаём роль пользователю
```

Comment: 'Command' object has no attribute 'has_permissions'

Comment: Дай свой код. Скорее всего у тебя не селф бот и отсюда проблема идёт. Я подправлю под твоего.